# click() function from click() function does not work

Tags: jquery

The problem is that when I click `delaccbut` button, the click function works, and shows the message, but when I click the `confdel` or `redel` button from the click function, it doesn't... Why?

`HTML:`

```
<span id='delaccspan'>
<button class='defbutt' id='delaccbut'>Delete my account</button>
</span>
```

`jQuery:`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#delaccbut").click(function(){
        $("#delaccspan").html("All your posts, pictures, followers and everything you did on this page will be deleted. Do you want to continue? <button class='smallbut' id='confdel'>Yes</button> <button class='smallbut' id='redel'>No</button>");
    });
    $("#confdel").click(function(){
        $("#delaccspan").html("Okay");
    });
    $("#redel").click(function(){
        $("#delaccspan").html("Good decision!");
    });
});
```

What is wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: There aren't elements with IDs of `confdel` or `redel` and you are attempting to target `delaccspan` with a dollar sign instead of a hash symbol.

Comment: omg that's typo -___- I'm blind sorry....

Comment: all of those click functions can be put into 1 document ready function as well.

Comment: Well so I fixed it and still... nothing shows up after clicking that button.. what do you mean by **There aren't elements with IDs of confdel or redel** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your yes and no buttons don't exist at the time the script is initialised. You need to delegate the event to a parent so that it can be applied to specific children wether they exist now or in the future.

See: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

```js
$(function(){
    $("#delaccbut").click(function(){
        $("#delaccspan").html("All your posts, pictures, followers and everything you did on this page will be deleted. Do you want to continue? <button class='smallbut' id='confdel'>Yes</button> <button class='smallbut' id='redel'>No</button>");
    });

    $("body").on("click", "#confdel", function(){
        $("#delaccspan").html("Okay");
    });

    $("body").on("click", "#redel", function(){
        $("#delaccspan").html("Good decision!");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id='delaccspan'>
<button class='defbutt' id='delaccbut'>Delete my account</button>
</span>
```

Comment: Is there a solution with $("#confdel").click() function? Or is your answer the only solution and my "way" of executing it is incorrect ?

Comment: There are always 'other' solutions but they'll all be forms of event delegation. You can't listen for a click on an element that doesn't exist. I suppose you could have the elements in existence all the time but toggle which one is shown.

Comment: @StevenDropper, the `on` method in `jQuery` watches for DOM changes. This is the only way to get those to hook up later.

Comment: Yeah, I got it now, so this basically means that jQuery searches the html as it is in real state, not as user/jQuery changes it?

Comment: jQuery/javascript sees the the live DOM (including any changes to it) but you asked it to add an event listener to an element that *wasn't* in the DOM at all (yet).